# RSS Feed, Parse all possible dates

Tags: java, php, objective-c, date, date-format

I am trying to parse the `pubDate` for rss feeds and facing a difficult issue. Every single site seems to have a different date format. I don't want to go over Google Reader because I have my own database.

So, except hardcoding all possible cases of `pubDate`, can I have a better option? If you can give me the source code, I am ok with C#, C, Java, Php and Objective-C. If you can suggest me a good library, I can only go with Php and Objective-C.

Here are all alternatives date format I found so far:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'

EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z

EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z

yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z
```

Well, I give up hardcoding the date format when it seems too risky now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://forrst.com/posts/NSDate_from_Internet_Date_Time_String-evA)

Then do:

```
// Replace line that sets articleDate to nil in parsers
NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];

// Replace line that sets articleDate to nil ni parseAtom
NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC3339];
```

Comment: Works really well, at least with all the cases that I am having here